# Ad Mediation - how to turn off?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I use Ad Mediation control for displaying advertisements. The user can buy off advertising. How to disable the Ad Mediation if the user has paid?

1.Visibility="Collapsed". But the component will interact with the ad networks.

2.Check at the start of the purchase, and download the user a different page without Ad Mediation.

3.Prompt the user to download a version of the application without advertising.

What do you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put an if condition that checks if the product has been purchased before calling for the Ad Service Function in your App. In this way, if a user has purchased the App then the App will never Enter the Ad-function and by a using a Bool to Visibility Converter drop the Ad Grid.